# How to install a Firefox Addon with nsis

Tags: installation, firefox-addon, nsis, xpi

How can I install a Firefox addon via nsis installer?

When I call Firefox with the .xpi extension it doesn't work and xpi extensions are not associated with Firefox either.

If I drop it to "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\extensions" then it tries to install every single time a user opened the Firefox. Never deletes the original xpi (*potentially due to the Vista UAC*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the correct command line parameter :)

```
firefox -install-global-extension c:\extension.xpi
```

Refer [documentation](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/firefox/extensions/commandlineoptions.html)

Answer (score 5):

Before Firefox 3.6 you could use the -install-global-extension parameter to install an extension. However it was [removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Command_Line_Options#Add-ons) in Gecko 1.9.2.  Possibly the best method to install extensions now is to create a registry entry as outlined in the [Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) page.